# Multiple Product Images Database Design

Tags: database, e-commerce

I'm trying to figure out the best way to add multiple product images for a given product. The amount of images will vary depending on the product.

I was thinking about using a **pivot table**. Do you have any other ideas? I'm also open to critiques of my overall design.

[My product db draft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asSGe.png)

Comment: a image can have more than one url?

Comment: No. So, the image that's in the Products table is the image that'll be displayed for the general, overall category. For example, if we go to the Sweaters section, we'll see all the sweaters (image in the Products table) we have to offer. But, each product can have multiple images. So, continuing with our example, when you click on the product in the Sweaters section, it'll show you the product details page.

Comment: In that case why you need productimageurl table?

Comment: The amount of images for a product will vary.

Comment: A product can have more than one image but each image have only one url in this case you can store image url in product image table itself